# What exactly can higher order functions in Haskell do that extended C can't?

Tags: c, haskell, lambda, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

GCC has [C extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html) which allows using nested functions.

Actually, I don't understand what exactly can higher order functions in Haskell do (or other pure functional language) that C (function pointers and nested functions extension) can't?

Comment: Higher-order functions are pretty much irrelevant to nested function definitions. You can write higher-order functions without this extension; just take a function pointer as an argument or return one.

Comment: yeah. the languages are just as "poweful", haskell just can do these higher order functional things without the verbosity that C needs. in the same way that C can handle state without the verbosity that haskell needs.

Comment: @SteveCox The verbosity being replacing `{` with `do`, `=` with `<-`, `;` with whitespace and `}` with unindentation? I'm not so sure that's so extremely verbose.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've never used this gcc extension; but I'll try to explain according to my interpretation of the link you gave.

As far as I understand the documentation, the crucial difference is that those nested functions don't allow you to build what a functional programmer would understand under "closure" -- those nested functions can't be used outside their definition context, because the stack variables they use get lost after the outside function exits.

In Haskell, when I do the following:

```hs
const x = \y -> x 
foo = const 2      -- remember or "close over" 2
bar = foo 1        -- now, bar == 2
```

You see that when applying `const` to `2`, the argument `2` gets "saved" by the closure which we have called `foo`. Afterwards, in `bar`, `2` can be recalled and returned -- because it still is remembered in `foo`. However, in C:

```c
typedef int (*int_to_int_fn)(int);
int_to_int_fn constant(int x)
{
  int constant_impl(int y) { return x; }
  return constant_impl;
}

int main()
{
   int_to_int_fn foo = constant(2);
   int bar = foo(1);
}
```

That probably doesn't even compile, but if it would, it would go against basic expectations we have of a C function: the `x` in `foo`, made out of the argument of `constant`, would need to stay somewhere (probably not on the stack!), until some time later `foo` gets called. That's not how stuff primitively works -- and C is primitive, in this sense (we'd probably need to allocate something on the heap, copy stuff, clean it up later, worry about references/values, etc.).

---

Some enlightenment can probably be achieved by looking at the C++11 lambda syntax. There, `constant_impl` could be written somewhere along this:

```c
auto constant_impl = [x](int y){ return x; }
```

The `[x]` part there is *exactly* the place where we tell the compiler "please, remember x for me!".

Comment: It compiles, but according to [the GCC documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html): _If you try to call the nested function through its address after the containing function exits, all hell breaks loose._

Answer (score 7):

A crucial thing for practical use of higher-order functions is that you want *closures*: a plain old C function can, apart from its parameters, only use global/static data. That means something like

> GHCi> filter (>4) [7,4,3,6,87,5,4]
>   [7,6,87,5]

can't really work, except if you define globally

```
bool largerThan4(int i) {return (i>4);}
```

which obviously doesn't scale. There is no way to "inject" the number 4 from somewhere else in your program. Functional languages pack this kind of information in closures.

Now, this GNU C extension gives you closures in a limited sense, I think it's the same sense that [C++11 defines for lambdas capturing by reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function#C.2B.2B_.28since_C.2B.2B11.29): a local function can refer to variables within its containing scope. That works reasonably well for, say,

```
typedef std::vector<int> IntArray;

IntArray filter (const IntArray& a, std::function<bool(int)> pred) {
  IntArray result;
  for(auto& i: a) if (pred(i)) result.push_back(i);
  return result;
}

int main() {
  std::vector<int> v{{7,4,3,6,87,5,4}};
  int minNumber = 4;
  for(auto i: filter(v, [&](int i){return i>minNumber;}))
    cout << i << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

(In C without range-loops etc. that would have been more cumbersome of course.) Here, the local anonymous function is used only while `minNumber` remains is the scope of `main`, so while `filter` keeps on calling that predicate it can always just point to that spot.

But that's a very simple scenario. In a functional language, you will normally use higher-order-functions much more pervasively, including techniques such as

- Returning a function from another function. That's already a problem with lexical closure – you can't reference to a local variable after it has left the scope! So you'll need to copy/move that variable out as an extra return.
- Using variables in closures that come from other closures themselves, which you have no direct control over. The closures can't stay around indefinitely, they'll need to be erased at some time – but how can the compiler know when it's safe? Functional languages are normally garbage-collected, which solves this issue.
- Recursion of a function with itself as an argument. This means there can effectively be loops of variable references (["tying the knot"](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Tying_the_knot)). Which usually means the program will hang unless you have lazy evaluation.